# SQL INSERT with sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns. I want to provide the 1st columns value but use a select statement to query another table to figure out the value that will go in the 2nd column of the first table.

Heres what I came up with but I know is wrong..

```
INSERT INTO VehicleModels_VehicleSubModels (VehicleModelId, VehicleSubModelYearId)
(SELECT @ModelId, VehicleSubModelYearId 
FROM VehicleSubYearIntermediate 
WHERE SubModelId=@SubModelId 
AND YearId=@YearId)
```

Essentially I want to provide the value for `VehicleModelId` through `@ModelId`, but it won't let me use it outside of the select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the brackets around the SELECT, as presumbably you're seeing an incorrect syntax error?

```
INSERT INTO VehicleModels_VehicleSubModels (VehicleModelId, VehicleSubModelYearId)
SELECT @ModelId,VehicleSubModelYearId 
FROM VehicleSubYearIntermediate 
WHERE SubModelId=@SubModelId 
    AND YearId=@YearId
```

Comment: The problem is that @ModelId doesn't come from the table in the select statement, it gets inserted based on a value of some asp.net control. I want to provide the value for VehicleModelId and just use the SELECT statement to provide the value for VehicleSubModelYearId.

Comment: That's what this is doing though....you pass in a value for @ModelId and that constant value will be used for each row returned by the SELECT and go into VehicleModelId.

Comment: Really? It seemed like it would check the other table for rows with a column that matched @ModelId. I found that it does work, I just had a problem with some other checks I was doing. Thanks for the clarification.